# GoodData Visualization SDK Initial Setup

Tags: node.js, git, sdk, visualization, gooddata

I followed the steps listed here http://sdk.gooddata.com/gooddata-js/getting-started/ to start setting up the local dev environment. However, I ran into this error when running the `npm install` command. Looks like I do not have access to copy the clone.

Here is more detail about the error:

```
new-host-2:gooddata-js zohebmunshi$ sudo npm install
Password:
Sorry, try again.
Password:
npm WARN package.json gooddata@0.0.13 No repository field.
The authenticity of host 'github.com (192.30.252.129)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48.
-|e you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? \
-/ease type 'yes' or 'no': \
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:gooddata/grunt-grizzly Cloning into bare repository '/Users/zohebmunshi/.npm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-gooddata-grunt-grizzly-41562694'...
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:gooddata/grunt-grizzly Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,192.30.252.129' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:gooddata/grunt-grizzly Permission denied (publickey).
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:gooddata/grunt-grizzly fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:gooddata/grunt-grizzly 
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:gooddata/grunt-grizzly Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:gooddata/grunt-grizzly and the repository exists.
npm ERR! Error: Command failed: Cloning into bare repository '/Users/zohebmunshi/.npm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-gooddata-grunt-grizzly-41562694'...
npm ERR! Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,192.30.252.129' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
npm ERR! Permission denied (publickey).
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR!     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:648:15)
npm ERR!     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
npm ERR!     at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
npm ERR!     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Darwin 13.3.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/zohebmunshi/gooddata-js
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.32
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! code 128
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/zohebmunshi/gooddata-js/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution: It needs to be executed from command line.

**root@edos-dp-dev-20 /var/www/phabricator # ./bin/repository pull M
Pulling 'M'... 

Enter passphrase for key '/tmp/b40shoorty8kw4os/passphrase-ssh-key':
@'s password: 
Done.**

root@edos-dp-dev-20 /var/www/phabricator #

Note: Where M is Callsign of repository

Additional information are here: https://secure.phabricator.com/T4620